# How to avoid undefined error occurs with my variable?

Tags: php, arrays, json, undefined

I have a php array like this:

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [12302]=>
    array(3) {
      [8766]=>
      array(6) {
        ["thumbnail"]=>
        string(...) "..."
        ["mainthumbnail"]=>
        string(...) "..."
        ["mp4url"]=>
        string(...) "..."
        ["webmurl"]=>
        string(...) "..."
        ["clipid"]=>
        string(4) "8766"
        ["title"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      [7346]=>
      array(6) {
        ["thumbnail"]=>
        string(...) "..."
        ["mainthumbnail"]=>
        string(...) "..."
        ["mp4url"]=>
        string(...) "..."
        ["webmurl"]=>
        string(...) "..."
        ["clipid"]=>
        string(4) "7346"
        ["title"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
      [2013]=>
      array(6) {
        ["thumbnail"]=>
        string(...) "..."
        ["mainthumbnail"]=>
        string(...) "..."
        ["mp4url"]=>
        string(...) "..."
        ["webmurl"]=>
        string(...) "..."
        ["clipid"]=>
        string(4) "2013"
        ["title"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [9803]=>
    array(1) {
      [2614]=>
      array(6) {
        ["thumbnail"]=>
        string(...) "..."
        ["mainthumbnail"]=>
        string(...) "..."
        ["mp4url"]=>
        string(...) "..."
        ["webmurl"]=>
        string(...) "..."
        ["clipid"]=>
        string(4) "2614"
        ["title"]=>
        string(5) "Titel"
      }
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    [9041]=>
    array(1) {
      [8766]=>
      array(6) {
        ["thumbnail"]=>
        string(...) "..."
        ["mainthumbnail"]=>
        string(...) "..."
        ["mp4url"]=>
        string(...) "..."
        ["webmurl"]=>
        string(...) "..."
        ["clipid"]=>
        string(4) "8766"
        ["title"]=>
        string(0) ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I pass that array to javascript like this:

```
var pdf_videos = <?php echo json_encode($pdf_videos); ?>;
```

Then I use this javascript function to receive the IDs:

```
if(typeof pdf_videos.map == 'function'){ 

        var topkeys = pdf_videos.map(function (k) {
            return Object.keys(k); 
        });
}
```

But it returns undefined. Why is it not working? This code is about PDF files. Every PDF can have one or more video files. If every PDF file have at least one video it works.

Comment: can you post the output of `console.log(pdf_videos)`

Comment: You need to parse it `var pdf_videos = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($pdf_videos); ?>');`

Comment: @Pranav - why would you convert json to string just to convert it json again? It's not necessary. var pdf_videos = <?php echo json_encode($pdf_videos); ?>; is 100% valid.

Comment: @PranavCBalan - No it's not, you'll just end up getting an error if you try to parse a javascript object and not a string.

Comment: Looks like you only have arrays in the three first levels, and Object.keys doesn't work on arrays.

Comment: nop check the output of `echo json_encode($pdf_videos); ?>`

Comment: @PranavCBalan - You're wrong, there's no quotes around the echo statement so it outputs a valid javascript object, not a JSON string.

Comment: check here http://in3.php.net/json_encode

Comment: @PranavCBalan - You're not getting it at all ?

Comment: console log output is undefined if not every PDF got at least one video and [["9802"], ["12302"], ["9803"], ["9041"]] (IDs of the PDFs) otherwise

Comment: it will Returns a string containing the JSON representation , in order to get object you need to parse it :)

Comment: @PranavCBalan - Jeezes, JSON is valid as a javascript object, even if PHP outputs a string into the javascript variable, that string is interpreted by the engine as an object in javascript when it's not quoted, not a string, **SO YOU'RE WRONG**, how hard can it be to test it out yourself and see that you've failed miserably.

Comment: is it a valid json object `{"1":"foo","2":"bar","3":"baz","4":"blong"}` without parsing it?

Comment: Guys please calm down! I don't think it has anything to do with the encoding but with the jQuery function. Because as I already said - it works if every PDF got at least one video-ID...

Comment: sorry for the interruption   ... @adeneo sorry sir, may be I will wrong

Comment: You don't have a jQuery function, you're using the native Array.map ?

Comment: Try something like -> http://jsfiddle.net/9Ngtt/

Comment: Yeah thanks. Now there is no error for the topkeys variable anymore! "Return true" did the trick. Thank you soo much, adeneo! :)

Comment: I figured out that it only works if the last pdf file has no video clip IDs. It does not work for the others. Probably the array needs to be in that structure: 0{},1{},2{},3{} and mine is 0{},1{},3{} if the third pdf doesn't have any clip IDs. Maybe I should try to reorder my array in php...